# Induce a Fayet-Iliopoulos term

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry

In a supersymmetric U(1) gauge theory, if I leave off the Fayet-Iliopoulos term $\kappa [V]_D$, what keeps it from being induced in loop corrections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My friend gave me a nice answer: the answer is in a paper by [Fischler, Niles, Polchinsky, Raby and Susskind](http://prl.aps.org/abstract/PRL/v47/i11/p757_1) (1981).

The Fayet-Iliopoulos term will not appear quantum mechanically if the trace of the U(1) generator $Q$ across all superfields of the theory vanishes $\text{Tr}(Q)=0$.